# GitLab CI - Cloning multiple repositories

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We are planning to migrate our code base from SVN to GitLab. For this, we are also doing POC to see if we can migrate our Jenkins jobs to GitLab CICD as well. As of now, we have below repository structure in GitLab under our project:

```
ci - contains all ant build files, configuration files and property files
projectA - This and all other project repositories contains just code
projectB
projectC
```

Our projects are developed using TIBCO tools and hence just need ant and java to build/deploy. With GitLab CI, we need to clone first our project specific repository, then ci repository, and then depending upon the project selected by user to build we need to clone other project repositories as well. As there are internal references which needs to be resolved before starting the build. Regardless of which project repository is selected for build, ci repository needs to be cloned every single time.

As I am new to GitLab, I am not sure if this can be achieved by having .gitlab-ci.yml in each project for it's build or keeping single kind of master .gitlab-ci.yml in ci repository and then clone necessary repositories depending on user input.

Can anyone please help so that I can at least start from somewhere.

Thanks,
Ranjeet

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not try to think Jenkins way. I am not sure how your old structure is setup, but in gitlab you are working a lot with dockerfiles and therefore can also create own docker images, which will be used for building.

Based on that i recommend you to generate an image for you builds containing all necessary files from the `ci` repository based on the used java version you need. After this you can use the generated image as your build image in your project. This way you can easily test also your CI setup locally as you can run the docker image in your local setup by mounting the project into the docker file.

For a more detailed look with more information i recommend to read the following pages:

- [What is an Image - GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-an-image)
- [GitLab Ci yml reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#image)
- [Best Practices Building a Docker Image with GitLab CI](https://blog.callr.tech/building-docker-images-with-gitlab-ci-best-practices/)

Alternatively you can always do a git checkout, but i do not recommend this, as the Docker image is in my opinion the best solution for such a usecase.